# Floating Divs Sorted By Columns Not Rows When Browser Resized

Tags: html, css

Thanks in advance for any help. I am a div rookie!

I have the following div scenario:

```
<div id="OuterContainer" style="float:left; width:100%">
    <div style="width:200px; float:left">Amy</div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left">Bob</div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left">Carl</div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left">Dan</div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left">Edith</div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left">Fran</div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left">Gary</div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left">Howard</div>
</div>
```

If I resize the width of the browser, I get the expected responsive design that I want, but I would like to have the div's stay in the order they were declared at the column level first, and then at the row level.

This is what I get now, where the div's sort across and then down:

[image: CURRENT]

But the desired outcome would be sorting down each column first, and then on to the next column, like this:

[image: DESIRED]

I have experimented with changing the css declarations for float, clear, display, etc. I do not know how many inner div's I will have in advance. The inner div's are generated as a string in C#, and then injected as a literal into the outer div. The outer div is declared in the HTML markup, and the inner div's are added as a literal within that div when a page the loaded using code behind.

Thanks again...

Comment: Use CSS columns.

Comment: OK Mr. Lister, that was way too easy. :-). Worked like a champ. I simply add a column-width property, without specifying the column-count property. Ty very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create columns:

```
<div id="OuterContainer" style="float:left; width:100%">
    <div style="width:200px; float:left">
        <div style="width:200px; float:left">Amy</div>
        <div style="width:200px; float:left">Bob</div>
        <div style="width:200px; float:left">Carl</div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:200px; float:left">
        <div style="width:200px; float:left">Dan</div>
        <div style="width:200px; float:left">Edith</div>
        <div style="width:200px; float:left">Fran</div>
    </div>

    <div style="width:200px; float:left">
        <div style="width:200px; float:left">Gary</div>
        <div style="width:200px; float:left">Howard</div>
    </div>
</div>
```